# php progress bar vs output buffer

Tags: php, apache

I'm using php 8.0 fpm wih proxy_fcgi on Apache.

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu)
```

I have a PHP script that takes around 20 seconds to execute...
I would like to have a progress bar showing the percent completed.
I am using a javascript function in conjunction with flush() and ob_flush() from the PHP side to modify the progress bar.

```
    $Flush_String=str_repeat(".", 4100);//for php flush purposes...
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Update_Progress($percent,\"$text\")</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById(\"nothing_div\").innerHTML=\"$Flush_String\";</script>";//for flush purposes...
    ob_flush();
    flush();
```

However, apache seems to be buffering on its own...

I tried including this in the VirtualHost section of my Apache config file

```
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost/" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10>
</Proxy>
```

But it makes my server throw some weird proxy_fcgi:error

Anyone have any advice to flush succesfully with php-fpm on Apache2?

Is there another strategy for creating a progress bar?

Thanks

Comment: Do you flush in a loop or just once?

Comment: I flush every time I send the new percentage to the javascript function

Comment: Weird question, but could the `max=10` and maybe more then 10 updates through flush could cause the problem?

Comment: Nah, tried it withouth the max=10 and got the same weird proxy_fcgi:error

Comment: “But it makes my server throw some weird proxy_fcgi:error” can you post the error?

Comment: Sure... Here's one:

[Tue Jan 09 13:44:36.271073 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 37413:tid 281473113518272] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 190.249.240.213:55860] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://blahblahblah.com/stuff.php

Comment: Here's another:

[Tue Jan 09 17:23:25.835629 2024] [core:warn] [pid 39147:tid 281473038331936] AH00045: child process 39149 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM

Comment: After I took out the Proxy directive, there's no error, but the progress bar doesn' work...

Comment: You can find apache config here: `/etc/httpd/` (for CentOS, Fedora, RHEL) and `/etc/apache2/` (for Debian & Ubuntu). then fine files which are usually named `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`, search for `ProxyTimeout` and set to whatever time you consider is required for execution of this scrip with some extra few seconds (for your VirtualHost).
For the error you have, have you tried to increase timeout in `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to `request_terminate_timeout = 60s`?

Comment: Maybe try to have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538548/ob-implicit-flush-flush-ob-flush-not-working-on-remote-server 
or as another solution you may try to use `ob_implicit_flush(1)` at the beginning of your script to turn off output buffering. Alternatively you can try using AJAX on client side, and update the prograss bar from the returned result, and you will be polling data every 1 second or so, or as alternative you can try use web sockets

Answer (score 1):

OK, as per Utmost Creator's comment, I did this:

```
header('Content-Encoding: none');
```

([ob_implicit_flush(), flush(), ob_flush() - not working on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538548/ob-implicit-flush-flush-ob-flush-not-working-on-remote-server))

And the progress bar is now working fine...

However I will keep trying out stuff, since this solution seems kind of fickle, as sometimes stuff like `session_start();` breaks the solution...

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps someone could explain the relation between headers, buffers and the PHP Session?